# Finding first samples greater than a threshold value efficiently in Python (and MATLAB comparison)

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, threshold

Instead of finding all the samples / data points within a list or an array which are greater than a particular `threshold`, I would like to find only the first samples where a `signal` becomes greater than a `threshold`. The signal might cross the threshold several times. For example if I have an example signal:

```
signal = [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 3, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 4, 8, 7, 6, 5, 0]
```

and a `threshold = 2`, then

```
signal = numpy.array(signal)
is_bigger_than_threshold = signal > threshold
```

would give me all values in `signal`which are greater than `threshold`. 
However, I would like to get only the first samples whenever signal becomes greater than threshold. Therefore, I am going through the whole list and make boolean comparisons like

```
first_bigger_than_threshold = list()
first_bigger_than_threshold.append(False)
for i in xrange(1, len(is_bigger_than_threshold)):
    if(is_bigger_than_threshold[i] == False):
        val = False
    elif(is_bigger_than_threshold[i]):
        if(is_bigger_than_threshold[i - 1] == False):
            val = True
        elif(is_bigger_than_threshold[i - 1] == True):
            val = False
    first_bigger_than_threshold.append(val)
```

This gives me the result I was looking for, namely

```
[False, False, True, False, False, False, False, False, False, True, False, False, False,   
False, False, False, True, False, False, False, False, False]
```

In MATLAB I would do similarily

```
for i = 2 : numel(is_bigger_than_threshold)
    if(is_bigger_than_threshold(i) == 0)
        val = 0;
    elseif(is_bigger_than_threshold(i))
        if(is_bigger_than_threshold(i - 1) == 0)
            val = 1;
        elseif(is_bigger_than_threshold(i - 1) == 1)
            val = 0;
        end
    end
    first_bigger_than_threshold(i) = val;
end % for
```

Is there a more efficient (faster) way to perform this calculation?

If I generate data in Python, e.g.

```
signal = [round(random.random() * 10) for i in xrange(0, 1000000)]
```

and time it, calculating these values took `4.45` seconds. If I generate data in MATLAB

```
signal = round(rand(1, 1000000) * 10);
```

and execute the program it takes only `0.92` seconds.

Why is MATLAB almost 5 times quicker than Python performing this task?

Thanks in advance for your comments!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The other answers give you positions of first Trues, if you want a bool array that marks the first True, you can do it faster:

```
import numpy as np

signal = np.random.rand(1000000)
th = signal > 0.5
th[1:][th[:-1] & th[1:]] = False
```

Comment: This solution is really even faster than the other two options above. Thanks.

Comment: It is indeed faster - and it scales better too. I suspect on large arrays there are fewer cache misses. Nice solution!

Answer (score 3):

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17242684/for-loop-in-python-is-10x-slower-than-matlab) explains why your code is slower than Matlab.

Try this code

```
import numpy as np

threshold = 2
signal = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 3, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 4, 8, 7, 6, 5, 0])

indices_bigger_than_threshold = np.where(signal > threshold)[0] # get item
print indices_bigger_than_threshold
# [ 2  3  4  5  9 16 17 18 19 20]
non_consecutive = np.where(np.diff(indices_bigger_than_threshold) != 1)[0]+1 # +1 for selecting the next
print non_consecutive
# [4 5]
first_bigger_than_threshold1 = np.zeros_like(signal, dtype=np.bool)
first_bigger_than_threshold1[indices_bigger_than_threshold[0]] = True # retain the first
first_bigger_than_threshold1[indices_bigger_than_threshold[non_consecutive]] = True
```

`np.where` returns indices that match the condition.

The strategy is to get indices upper than `threshold` and remove the consecutive.

BTW, welcome to Python/Numpy world.

Comment: Thank you for the link to the explanation about the JIT accelerator. That's good to know when using loops. Tested your version above which works fine and took only `0.02` seconds on my machine.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the notion that the best way to speed things up is to pick the best algorithm, you can do this neatly with a simple edge detector:

```
import numpy

signal = numpy.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 3, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 4, 8, 7, 6, 5, 0])

thresholded_data = signal > threshold
threshold_edges = numpy.convolve([1, -1], thresholded_data, mode='same')

thresholded_edge_indices = numpy.where(threshold_edges==1)[0]

print(thresholded_edge_indices)
```

prints `[2 9 16]`, the indices corresponding to first entry in a sequence greater than the threshold. This will make things faster in both Matlab and Python (with Numpy) - on my machine about 12ms to do what took you 4.5s.

Edit: As pointed out by @eickenberg, the convolution can be replaced with `numpy.diff(thresholded_data)`, which is conceptually a bit simpler, though in that case the indices will be out by 1, so remember to add those back in, and also to convert `thresholded_data` to be an array of ints with `thresholded_data.astype(int)`. There is no appreciable speed difference between the two methods.

Comment: This looks like the way to go. I propose using `numpy.diff` for clarity and probably speed (edit proposed).

Comment: It's actually _slightly_ slower using `numpy.diff` (though doubtless not enough to worry about) (and it wasn't rejected by me!).

Comment: @Henry Gomersall: Thank you for your suggestion with the edge detector. This works for me as well and yields a similar speed than mskimm's solution on my PC.

Comment: @xaneon make sure you initialise your array as a numpy array - converting between lists will slow you down if you need to do this lots of times.

Comment: Thanks for testing that! The fact that `np.diff` is not faster can be due to sample size. If it is always slower then this is really interesting, since that means that `np.convolution` does its (somewhat more general) job really efficiently even in specific cases such as this one. If using `np.diff` watch out that you use it on `thresholded_data.astype(int)`, since otherwise all differences will just evaluate to `True`, also the `-1` ones.

Comment: @eickenberg On rechecking, the timing difference is not substantial and is actually the other way around (11ms for the `diff` vs 12ms for `convolve`). I'll add a comment about `astype`. It's not wholly unexpected - a length 2 convolution is not exactly onerous!

Comment: Is it possible to use this code to find the last instead of the first point?

Comment: @VictorAguiar sure, just change the comparison to `-1` and subtract one from the indices (since -1 is the next value below the threshold). Note that this will ignore a run that never drops below the threshold at the end of a sequence because it only detects transitions.

Comment: @HenryGomersall thank you so much for your support! It helped a lot!